# Flutter Firebase authStateChanges() with Provider & NullSafety On

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I have seen many questions like this, but most of them are outdated and not using null safety.

I am using FirebaseAuth and provider to stream & update the users state (Is he logged in or not)

what's wrong with this code?

**AuthenticationProvider Class**

```
class AuthenticationProvider {
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth;
  AuthenticationProvider(this._firebaseAuth);

   Stream<User?> get authState => _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges();
  
}
```

**main.dart**

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        Provider<AuthenticationProvider>(
          create: (_) => AuthenticationProvider(FirebaseAuth.instance),
        ),
        StreamProvider(
          create: (context) =>
              context.read<AuthenticationProvider>().authState,
          initialData: null,
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        
        home: SplashScreen(),
        
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**SplashScreen() class**

```
 class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final firebaseUser = context.watch<User>();
    
        if (firebaseUser != null) { // This line warning: The operand can't be null, so the condition is always true. Remove the condition.
          return Dashboard();
        }
        return StartingScreen();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Should the watch be `final firebaseUser = context.watch<User?>();`?

Comment: its works! Thank you. But The logout doesn't take to the logout screen and need to restart the app to see the change.

Comment: Looking for a solution all the way around and added await for the signOut event but still nothing happening... Why the stream is not calling when signOut? Signing In is perfectly working

Comment: Found it, its because I placed the signout button in a AppDrawer. So need to pop the  drawer before calling the `FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();`

Comment: Good to hear you figured it out! 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that you start with a stream of `User?`:

```
Stream<User?> get authState => _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges();
```

I think the `watch` should be on `User?` too. So:

```
final firebaseUser = context.watch<User?>();
```