# Could not find the correct Provider<User> above this AuthWrapper Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I am trying to fix this error

> Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this AuthWrapper Widget.

Following this tutorial but it doesnt seem to work for me.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yyD_VqSrKd8

here is the code:

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:untitled2/firbaseauth.dart';
import 'package:untitled2/homescreen.dart';
import 'package:untitled2/startpage.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        Provider<Authservis>(
          create: (_) => Authservis(FirebaseAuth.instance),
        ),
        StreamProvider(create: (context) => context.read<Authservis>().authStateChanges, 
initialData: null,),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: "APP",
        home: AuthWrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AuthWrapper extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = context.watch<User>();

    if(user != null){
      return Homescreen();
    }
    return Startpage();
  }

}
```

Comment: Maybe check this out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68122434/flutter-firebase-authstatechanges-with-provider-nullsafety-on

Answer (score 0):

The error exactly tells you that there is no `Provider` named `User` above the widget that calls such provider.

Your `MultiProvider` at the top of your tree includes just a `Auhtservis` provider, but in order to use your `User` provider, the list should include the `User` provider, too.

Also, youtube tutorials aren't perfect, if you lecturer uses this precise code you might want to notify them.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any `Provider` with `User` type above your `AuthWrapper`. I think the correct code should be this:

```
final authService = context.watch<AuthService>();
// check if user is logged in
```

Answer (score 0):

try giving your `StreamProvider` a type of `User`

```dart
  StreamProvider<User>(create: (context) => context.read<Authservis>().authStateChanges, 
initialData: null,),
```

Comment: that cant work because user and stream are fromdiffernt packages